# How to replace values only in a subset of a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm currently trying to figure out how to replace a subset of values in my pandas DataFrame. This is the solution I've come up with, but it runs too slowly (still hasn't terminated after 5 minutes).

```
new = df.loc[:, df.dtypes != "O"]
new = new.mask(new < 0)
df.loc[:, df.dtypes != "O"] = new
df
```

Comment: Please paste your DataFrame and the results you need, without these I can't help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Numpy* is known to operate faster than *Pandas*.

So use the following code base on *np.where*:

```
for col in df:
    if df[col].dtype != 'O':
        df[col] = np.where(df[col] >= 0, df[col], np.nan)
```

I performed a test using *%timeit* on a DataFrame of shape *(50000, 3)*
(1 *string*, 1 *int* and 1 *float* column) and got the time about
**3 times shorter** than for your code, whereas the other solution is only
marginally better than yours.

And a note about the usage of *%timeit*: Since your code alters the
source DataFrame, then before each test you have to:

- create the DataFrame again (or copy it from some source),
- run *%timeit* with *-r1* and *-n1* options (perform a **single**
  test run).

Otherwise subsequent executions of the tested code operate on a
**changed** DataFrame (the result of previous execution).